# How to upload image(s) through SQL queries?

Tags: directus

I want to upload images through `SQL` queries. But I can't because the `image field` is `UUID` type.

How can I upload? My file location is server and I don't want to store them on the database. Just on the server and then give a relative `URL`.

Answer (score 1):

To upload a file in Directus, POST the `multipart/form-data` as the encoding type to the `/files` endpoint.

The file contents has to to be provided in a part called file. All other properties of the file object can be provided as parts as well.

https://docs.directus.io/reference/api/system/files/#upload-a-file

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I do this with raw SQL queries? I want to make bulk upload so SQL is more suitable for me